# How to add more Titles in this Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Javascript/Jquery Expert,

i Have this script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('doom');
    setInterval(function() {
        f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
    }, 1000); 

});

<div id="doom">1st Title</div>
```

Here is its [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XRcJ/876/):

**Question:** if you see the above script it blink only **1st Title**, now i want to add atleast **5 titles** to the html code and it should display one by one.

like this sequence:

```
1st title
2nd title
3rd title
4th title
5th title
```

It should display one by one with same blinking. Please also share fiddle example thanks.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then use it for the dom manipulation also ...  `var f = $('#doom');    setInterval(function() {  f.toggle();    }, 1000); `. No point loading the library if you aren't going to use it

Comment: What you are asking for is not hard to find in any number of slideshow type tutorials. This isn't a tutorial or code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl please share the full code, how can i display all those titles one by one, when 1st title blink then it should disappeared and blink 2nd title and so one, please share the code

Comment: @charlietfl i tried my best, but i am stuck with it. please if you can do it. thanks bundles

Comment: *"please share the code"* is not how this site works. People aren't here to do your work for you

Comment: @charlietfl So, what we are help in stackoverflow, what type of help can we get here ?

Comment: Help with code that you have that attempts to solve a problem but isn't working as expected. Not to take a simple single use case and expand it into more complex logic that requires multiple steps. Also you are expected to do your own research first and finding content slider scripts is not hard on the web

Comment: @charlietfl but this will take 2 or 3 minutes to write the code. only i want to add the other titles thats is.

Comment: And would only take you a few minutes to find tutorials for something like this. Again...this is not a code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl i have already searched for it but did not find the solution thats why i came here. would you kindly guide me on which query should i find the exact coding on web ?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if you are using jQuery you don't need to do document.getElementById to access the element. You can just say $("#myID"). Here's my solution. Hope it helps :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var str = "";
   var number = 1;
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
     if(number == 1){str = "professional designer"}
     else if(number == 2){str = "professional business speaker"}
     else if(number == 3){str = "professional marketer"}
     else if(number == 4){str = "professional SEO consultant"} 
     $("#test").html("<div>"+ str+"</div>").fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
     ++number;
     $("#doom").remove();
     if(number == 5){
     clearInterval(timer);
     }
    }, 1000); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "test">
<div id="doom">professional blogger</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the code, however, we have bit misunderstanding, your script display all titles one after another, while i want, that if f1st title display it should then disappeared and 2nd title should display and then it should it disappeared and 3rd title should display. not all should be visible. it should be visible 1st title then it should unvisible and visible the 2nd title. i hope you have got my point. thanks.

Comment: @JohnBelly So you want to show 1st Tilte, then hide it, then show 2 Title, then hide it, then show 3 Title and so on?

Comment: @JohnBelly I just updated my code. Is that what you needed :) ?

Comment: @JohnBelly With a few alterations to Henry's answer https://jsfiddle.net/py3hj7oc/

Comment: @HenryDev No, it update too fast, it has no blinking motion like it slowly display and hide, it just update with number statically. It should be in slow motion to hide and display every title.

Comment: @JohnBelly adjust the interval time if you want it to wait longer. If you want to have a smooth transition then I suggest you use some CSS. This is showing you how to change the title as you asked. It's up to you to expand on the answer to make it fit your needs.

Comment: @JohnBelly I jus updated my answer again for the blinking :). Let me know what you think?

Comment: @NewToJS Ofcourse i will do that, but here is another problem too in the script, it update only numbers like this: 1st title and then it display second like this 2st title. which is wrong. i want on every blink my own set title. here it update only number. it should display the whole title. like 1st tilte and hide it and display 2nd titles and hide it 3rd title. not just increase number like this: 1st title, 2st title, 3st title.

Comment: @JohnBelly did you see my updated solution. I update the numbers and the text :)

Comment: @HenryDev but how i will update the titles with my original texts like this: Its john, I am designer, i will work better, check our portfolio, visit us.                  these are all titles after comma. how can i add these titles instead of those 1st title, 2nd titles to show these titles.

Comment: @HenryDev add these five titles to the script: professional blogger, professional designer, professional business speaker, professional marketer, professional SEO consultant.  how to add these titles to the script. ?

Comment: @JohnBelly You asked many questions all at once. But I updated my solution again to show the titles  you want. Please mark my solution as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @HenryDev thanks a lot for your help. thats i wanted.

Comment: @HenryDev i marked as answer but it says i have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: @JohnBelly even if you can't vote it up for having less han 15 reputation points you can still ACCEPT the answer as the correct one. Simply click on the Check Mark that is on the left of my answer. Here's an example how: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow  . Please appreciate my time and help :)